# windows nt error and elifecycle error in node js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

im am trying to fix a problem with some code a buddy of mine wrote. He cant answer my question so i am asking you
if i press a specific button in the program the server will crash.
this is the npm debug log i got:

```
`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Programme\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Programme\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart KTB@0.0.0
6 info start KTB@0.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info KTB@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: KTB@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
10 verbose pkgid KTB@0.0.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Bankprogramm\Kidstownbank_V1\KTB
12 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
13 error argv "C:\\Programme\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Programme\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v0.12.7
15 error npm  v2.11.3
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error KTB@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the KTB@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the KTB package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node ./bin/www
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls KTB
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`
```

Has anybody some ideas how to fix this problem?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you share folder structure?

Comment: C:\Bankprogramm\Kidstownbank_V1\KTB\bin
C:\Bankprogramm\Kidstownbank_V1\KTB\db
C:\Bankprogramm\Kidstownbank_V1\KTB\node_modules
C:\Bankprogramm\Kidstownbank_V1\KTB\public
C:\Bankprogramm\Kidstownbank_V1\KTB\routes
C:\Bankprogramm\Kidstownbank_V1\KTB\views

those are all folders i´ve got

Comment: Well this is the issue regarding your start directory.  (1.)are you able to run `npm -v` from this directory? (2.) run `npm config get` and share the out put.